# List Permissions and Workflows

Tags: workflow

I have full control of a list.  I am trying to build a workflow that will update a field based on information being populated from another field.  I know how to use SharePoint Designer but don't have access to that tool.  I am unfamiliar with their existing workflows as I don't think this team really use them.  I'm new to this team.  Can you assist me with creating a workflow within the List?

My example is:

> Update "Status Field" to choice "yes"  when  "Are you ready" field is
>   changed to "start".

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have access to SharePoint Designer, then you cannot create custom workflows. If you are using SharePoint Online, then you could use Flow.

It sounds like a pretty simple Calculated Column will do what you described. Something like:

```
=IF( [Status Field] = "yes", "Start", "some other msg")
```